# Cannot read property 'get' of null of Reactive form component testing with angular

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-reactive-forms, formbuilder

I am trying to create a unit test for my `input` component which is wrapped inside Reactive FormBuilder

This is my component

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { RequiredInput } from 'src/app/core/decorators/required-input.decorator';
import { ControlContainer, FormGroupDirective, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'es-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.scss'],
  viewProviders: [
    {
      provide: ControlContainer,
      useExisting: FormGroupDirective,
    },
  ],
})
export class InputComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input()
  @RequiredInput
  esId: string;

  @Input()
  esType = 'text';

  @Input()
  esPlaceholder = '';

  @Input()
  esIsAutocompleteOn: boolean;

  @Input()
  esDisabled: boolean;

  @Input()
  esReadOnly: boolean;

  @Output()
  esOnInputChange: EventEmitter<string | number> = new EventEmitter();

  @Input()
  esPrepend: string;

  @Input()
  esAppend: string;

  @Input()
  esNoIcon: boolean;

  @Input()
  esHelp: string;

  @Input()
  esMaxLength: number;

  @Input()
  @RequiredInput
  esControlName: string;

  @Input()
  @RequiredInput
  esParentForm: FormGroup;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes && changes.esDisabled) {
      if (changes.esDisabled.currentValue) {
        this.esParentForm.get(this.esControlName).disable();
      } else {
        this.esParentForm.get(this.esControlName).enable();
      }
    }
  }

  onInputChange(value: string | number): void {
    this.esOnInputChange.emit(value);
  }

  get required(): boolean {
    return (
      this.esParentForm.get(this.esControlName).hasError('required') &&
      this.esParentForm.get(this.esControlName).touched
    );
  }

  get invalid(): boolean {
    return (
      !this.required &&
      this.esParentForm.get(this.esControlName).errors &&
      this.esParentForm.get(this.esControlName).dirty
    );
  }

  get invalidLength(): boolean {
    return (
      this.esParentForm.get(this.esControlName).hasError('minlength') ||
      this.esParentForm.get(this.esControlName).hasError('maxlength')
    );
  }

  get inputLength(): string {
    return this.esParentForm.get(this.esControlName).value.length;
  }
}
```

My template is this

```
<input
      class="element"
      [type]="esType"
      [ngClass]="{
        'no-icon': esNoIcon,
        invalid: required || invalid
      }"
      [placeholder]="esPlaceholder"
      [id]="esId"
      [autocomplete]="esIsAutocompleteOn ? 'on' : 'off'"
      (input)="onInputChange($event.target.value)"
      [readonly]="esReadOnly"
      [formControlName]="esControlName"
    />
```

This is my `spec` file

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { InputComponent } from './input.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormGroupDirective, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

describe('InputComponent', () => {
  let component: InputComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<InputComponent>;
  const formBuilder: FormBuilder = new FormBuilder();

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
      declarations: [InputComponent],
      providers: [
        FormGroupDirective,
        {
          provide: FormBuilder,
          useValue: formBuilder,
        },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(InputComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.esParentForm = formBuilder.group({
      basic: [''],
    });
    component.esControlName = 'basic';
    component.esId = 'basic-input';
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create 4', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Even i already create a `formBuilder.group` before `fixture.detectChanges();`

But i still got `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of null`
[image]

How could i fix this or what do missed in my spec file?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you test it manually? Seems that after update to chrome 80 there is an issue with first attempt to `get()` usage. Either check if issue appear if testing manually or change to `controls[foo]`

Comment: @LukaszBalazy what do you mean by test it manually?

Comment: I think it was my bad, don't know if our issues are related. You could check if this issue still exists if you open the page manually in firefox unless you are doing it in other browser than chrome.

Comment: got this `TypeError: this.form is null in http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js` in Firefox launcher

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling somewhere where you're doing `this.esParentForm.get`, `this.esParentForm` is `null` either in your `ngOnChanges` or in all of the getters (`get`).

I also feel that on the `ngClass` there is a class being applied if these getters are true (`required || invalid`) but these are related to `this.esParentForm` so the class cannot be applied if the form does not exist yet.

Try adding an `*ngIf` on the input element to only be painted once `esParentForm` is truthy:

```
  <input
      *ngIf="esParentForm" // <=== This line
      class="element"
      [type]="esType"
      [ngClass]="{
        'no-icon': esNoIcon,
        invalid: required || invalid
      }"
      [placeholder]="esPlaceholder"
      [id]="esId"
      [autocomplete]="esIsAutocompleteOn ? 'on' : 'off'"
      (input)="onInputChange($event.target.value)"
      [readonly]="esReadOnly"
      [formControlName]="esControlName"
    />
```